# Total row while combining tablesorter + csvtotable

Tags: jquery, tablesorter

Just completed my first html to present data from a csv file into nice tables. My problem now is that I need to add a total row, and realize that:

1. I have no options in csvtotable (as far as I know) to tag the last row as a total, with `<tfoot>`
2. I can not add info into the just-converted-from-csv-html-file because it actually doesn't exist: something like adding the totals in the second row and tag them as `<tbody class="tablesorter-no-sort">`.
3. Perhaps another way would be creating a second table with just one row and adding at the top or bottom of the main table: I am afraid in this case I'll find issues with the column width, as they will be different in both tables.

Is there any way I can manage to add or identify the totals row in my output?
Thanks,

Just as a reference, my simple code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../js/ts/css/theme.default.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../js/ts/js/jquery.tablesorter.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../js/ts/js/jquery.tablesorter.widgets.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../js/csv/js/jquery.csvToTable.js"></script>

<script>
$(function() {
   $('#myTable').CSVToTable('fam.txt',
{
startLine: 1,
separator: ";"
}
).bind("loadComplete",function() {
   $(document).find('#myTable').tablesorter({sortList: [[0,0], [1,0]],widgets:
   ["zebra", "stickyHeaders"]});
});;
});
</script>

</head>
<body>

<table id="myTable" class="tablesorter">
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to manipulate the table, do so within the "loadComplete" event function.

Try this:

```
$(function() {
  var mytable = $('#myTable')
    .CSVToTable('fam.txt',{
      startLine: 1,
      separator: ";"
    })
    .bind("loadComplete",function(){
      var footer = mytable.find('tr:last');
      // if you try to append a tr wrapped in a tfoot, jQuery will assume you are
      // adding a tr and put it inside the tbody... so target the tfoot (parent)
      mytable
        .find('thead').after( footer.wrap('<tfoot/>').parent() ).end()
        .tablesorter({
          sortList: [[0,0], [1,0]],
          widgets: ["zebra", "stickyHeaders"]
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Great! Thanks. By the way, could `theme.default.css` file  have a typo: until I changed `.tablesorter-default tfoot th` by `.tablesorter-default tfoot td` the footer was not configured properly. Far from being an expert, anyhow. Great work with tablesorter, @Mottie. Thanks.